# How to click on same Button from another Software via Image

Tags: python, pyautogui

I have a img (attached here) and I want to have a python loop thats when it shows up just click it.

I try example

```
import pyautogui


location = pyautogui.locateOnScreen(r'C:\Users\Admin\Music\image_autoclicks-master\input_images\1.png')

pyautogui.click(location)
```

it should be infi loop always when the img show click it.

[click on this button when he see it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PXPpF.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PXPpF.png)